# Create own powerpoint animation in VB

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I create my own PowerPoint animations in VB?
Not sure where I can find the right commands etc..
I am somewhat familiar with VB...
Is it even possible to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: You can certainly mimic much of PowerPoint's animation behavior in XAML (which can be written in VB for WPF/Silverlight apps), but I'm not sure if that is what you're shooting for.

Comment: +1 (when i get my votes back!) silverlight animations in PPT could be killer for a preso.

Answer (score 3):

Powerpoint has a rich COM object model that you can access from VB, heres a [Microsoft resource](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4DAAU_enAU208AU208&q=vb+com+powerpoint) that explains how to do it.

It can be difficult findoug out what classes do what, so a good first approach is to turn on the macro recorder in Powerpoint, do the operation that you'd like to automate in VB, and then look at the VBA code that the macro recorder has created. The VBA and VB code will be pretty much identical.